# Explain this MySQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

Could someone explain me this MYSQL statement?

```
select race_id from (
select race_id,sum(if(bsp=0,1,0)) notran,count(*) ran
from runners
group by race_id
)lw
where ran=notran
```

Why there is lw there? 
Could you point me some link where I can study about this type of statements.

Comment: `lw` is alias name of your `inner query`. Check http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lw` is alias for this sub-select part. It's similar to

```
SELECT lw.race_id FROM runners lw
```